# При редактировании записи обновить все все связанные с ним статьи

Tags: django

Имеется несколько записей, которые связанные одним названием главы

При редактирование одной записи, в случае если меняется название главы, то оно должно меняться во всех записях.

Пробовал сделать следующим образом

```
def post_edit(request, id, slugpost):
    user = request.user.id
    post_user = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slugpost)
    
    if request.method == 'POST' and user == post_user.autor_id:
        user_edit_post = EditPost(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post_user)
        if user_edit_post.is_valid():
            post_done = user_edit_post.save(commit=False)
            post_done.autor = request.user
            Post.objects.filter(glava=post_user.glava).update(glava=request.POST.get("id_glava"))
            post_done.save()
            user_edit_post.save_m2m()
```

Но, как понимаете, это не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется вам нужно сначала получить старую главу.

```py
    post_user = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slugpost)
    old_glava = post_user.glava
```

А потом искать записи по ней

```py
        user_edit_post = EditPost(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post_user)
        if user_edit_post.is_valid():
            post_done = user_edit_post.save(commit=False)
            post_done.autor = request.user
            Post.objects.filter(glava=old_glava).update(glava=post_done.glave)
            post_done.save()
            user_edit_post.save_m2m()
```

Почему? Потому что в форме хранятся уже новые значения.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Вокруг решения весь день кругами ходил...